# D3.js Tooltip with filled area graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been trying many different examples (and answers on SO) to get a tooltip working on a filled area graph, but have been struggling to come up with a working solution.

I am basing the tooltip off of this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569 and the actual graph is from another example implemented extremely similar. I've been trying to wrap my head around why it isn't working but I get multiple console errors like this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined
```

from this line of code

```
d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
```

Here is my code http://bl.ocks.org/Frozenfire92/80ba8c6f844cf48708c4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `d3.bisect` assumes that the data is sorted, but yours isn't. Therefore it is unable to find the proper element in the data array. The fix is simple -- sort the data:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) { return a.date - b.date; });
```

Complete demo [here](https://vida.io/documents/3hp5GxZfE2tmJ3Fm2).

Comment: Thank you! Easy thing to overlook, glad to have a second set :)